# How do I change the locale for the datepicker in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, locale

I have an Xamarin.Forms app that supports both English and French. How do I show the Calender (Month, Day of the Week text) for the DatePicker in French locale? 
[image: Imgur]

I've tried Xamarin.Forms

```
    public void SetLocale(CultureInfo ci)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Console.WriteLine("CurrentCulture set: " + ci.Name);
    }
```

I've tried changing the context before creating the datepicker dialog in my DatePicker custom renderer

```
        var config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration { Locale = Locale.CanadaFrench };
        Context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

        _dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
        {
            view.Date = e.Date;
            ((IElementController)view).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
        }, year, month, day);
```

I also tried this in my DatePicker custom renderer
protected override void

```
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            this.Control.TextLocale = Locale.CanadaFrench;
        }
```

None of these did anything to change the locale.

I also found this post that seems have done changing the calendar view to a different locale
[Set Android DatePicker title language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871800/set-android-datepicker-title-language)
But it wasn't clear how it was accomplished.

Comment: generally the user changes locale via the device's settings, not on an app-by-app basis

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you have to add French as a language in the settings in order to show stuff in French.

Settings->General Management -> Language and Input->Language[image: Language Settings]

And you just need these two lines in your DatePicker android Custom renderers to make the calendar French

```
this.Control.TextLocale = locale;
Resources.Configuration.SetLocale(locale);
```

If you title still remains in English, reference this post
[Set Android DatePicker title language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871800/set-android-datepicker-title-language)

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr"); 
Control.TextLocale = locale; 
Android.Content.Res.Configuration config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration(); 
config.Locale = locale;
Locale.SetDefault(Locale.Category.Format, locale);
Resources.Configuration.SetLocale(locale);
Resources.Configuration.Locale = locale;
```