# Datepicker localization for Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, localization, custom-renderer

Anyone can share them a workaround for this bug, I also need to implement the Localization for Datepicker,
I implementing the Localization in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=windows

Then Translate and Change the Culture using this

```
public void SetLocale(CultureInfo ci)
{
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Console.WriteLine("CurrentCulture set: " + ci.Name);
 }
```

But the app still using the Device OS culture setting.

I also try Custom Renderer.

```
public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{
    public CustomDatePickerRenderer(Context context) :base(context)
    {            
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Locale locale = new Locale("ARA");
        Control.TextLocale = locale;
        Resources.Configuration.SetLocale(locale);
        Resources.Configuration.Locale = locale;
        Resources.Configuration.SetLayoutDirection(locale);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure which "bug" you are referring to, maybe this one?:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871800/set-android-datepicker-title-language/45889476#45889476

Comment: var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this);
dialog.Show();
SetHeaderMonthDay(dialog, Locale.Korean);


Where I can get the "This" inside my DatepickerRenderer?

Comment: @parpar The `this` in the sample represents the `Context`. You can get the context from the `CustomDatePickerRenderer` constructor. Save it into a private field and use it whenever you need later.

Comment: @SushiHangover can share the link where I can get the date_picker_header_date.xml ? thanks

Comment: @parpar, It seems that it depend on system language, can not change datepicker title language by custom render.